# Reduce the time of computation for $5$-dimensional numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, timing

I need to perform (numerically) the $5$-dimensional integral given in the code below for a large number of values of $\epsilon$. The code I have at the moment takes $\sim 11$ minutes and returns an error of almost $25$% for $\epsilon = 10$. I cannot say exactly what is the accuracy that I am targeting (for sure less than $1$%), but first I would like to reduce the computational time as much as possible. I tried the following already:

$\bullet$ `ComplexExpand` the whole thing and set `SymbolicProcesing` to `0` as recommended in the documentation. This did not have any noticeable impact. Also tried moving the `Chop` in and out `NIntegrate`, and this had also no effect.

$\bullet$ set the variable type to `NumericQ` for each function, as well as for the function `integrand` only. In both cases this *doubled* the computation time!

$\bullet$ change the method to `GaussKronodRule`. In that case the computation ran for over a hour (!) without giving any output. I tried `MultidimensionalRule`, and that gave the same result as `Automatic` in a similar time.

Is that computational time normal? Or do you have any suggestion for how to reduce it? I have very little experience in numerical integration, I am looking forward to your ideas!

Here is my code so far:

```
ϵ = 10;
d[x_, y_, z_] := x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
I15[x_, y_, z_, τ_] := 1/((1 - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 + τ^2);
R[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := (1 + τ4^2) I15[x, y, z, τ];     
S[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (τ - τ4)^2) I15[x, y, z, τ];
a[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := 1/4 Sqrt[4*R[x, y, z, τ, τ4]*S[x, y, z, τ, τ4] - (1 - R[x, y, z, τ, τ4] - S[x, y, z, τ, τ4])^2];
F[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := I Sqrt[-((1 - R[x, y, z, τ, τ4] - S[x, y, z, τ, τ4] - 4 I*a[x, y, z, τ, τ4])/(1 - R[x, y, z, τ, τ4] - S[x, y, z, τ, τ4] + 4 I*a[x, y, z, τ, τ4]))];
Phi[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := 1/a[x, y, z, τ, τ4] Im[PolyLog[2, F[x, y, z, τ, τ4] Sqrt[R[x, y, z, τ, τ4]/S[x, y, z, τ, τ4]]] + Log[Sqrt[R[x, y, z, τ, τ4]/S[x, y, z, τ, τ4]]]*Log[1 - F[x, y, z, τ, τ4] Sqrt[R[x, y, z, τ, τ4]/S[x, y, z, τ, τ4]]]];
integrand[x_, y_, z_, τ_, τ4_] := I15[x, y, z, τ]^3/d[x, y, z]^(1/2) (4 τ^2 I15[x, y, z, τ] - 1) Phi[x, y, z, τ, τ4];

Chop[NIntegrate[integrand[x, y, z, τ, τ4], {τ4, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, 1 - ϵ/2}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞}, {τ, -∞, ∞}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, IntegrationMonitor :> ((errors1 = Through[#1@"Error"]) &)]] // Timing
Total@errors1

(* {688.916,-0.180996} *)
(* 0.0434532 *)
```

**EDIT**:

I have noticed the following things in the past days:

$\bullet$ Monte Carlo is not really an option, since the results are too inaccurate (they seem to be underestimates). Maybe it's because the high values (near $1-\epsilon/2$) are not taken into consideration, and maybe there is a way to give this region more weight.

$\bullet$ Increasing `MaxErrorIncreases` seems to give a better result, but unfortunately increases the computing time linearly. If I use `GlobalAdaptive` and set `MaxErrorIncreases` to `8000`, I get a computing time of nearly $3$ hours for an error of about $5$%.

By the way I realized since writing this post that for my purposes I must take a much smaller $\epsilon$, something like $0.0001$. This makes it even more difficult I guess, as the peak gets even stronger.

Comment: Just a sanity check: Do you have any reason to believe that the integral were finite?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, the integral diverges at $\epsilon = 0$ but is finite for other positive values of $\epsilon$ (note the integration limits for $x$). I have already performed a set of such measurements overnight at low accuracy which confirmed that. Why would you think it is not finite? $-0.180996$ is not a high number.

Comment: Related to my previous comment: the integrand takes its highest values for $x$ near $1-\epsilon/2$, maybe that is a useful information.

Comment: When I run into intractable integrals like this usually I try to see if I can apply some ansatz to simplify it to maybe a product of lower-dimensional integrals without sacrificing _too much_ accuracy. If I need to do this integration for a large number of parameter values, then this can be a useful way to get information about the parameter space which I can then use to do more accurate computations in regions of interest. Basically do some symbolic/intuitive work up front to get insights that can be used later.

Comment: It is not much, but the can reduce this by one dimensions by using polar coordinates for `{u,z}`: `y` and `z` appear always together as `y^2 + z^2`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Nice catch, it seems like that reduced the computing time by $\sim 30$% and the error to $\sim 5$% (with the same settings as in the original post)! So that's actually a super useful remark!

Comment: Just a side note: Do not forget to multply the integrand by `2 Pi r` before integrating over `r` to account for the change in coordinates.

Comment: Another note: To plot the behavior with respect to $\varepsilon$, you need no integrate over the full infinite-dimensional domain. By comparing against the fixed number obtained with `{x, -∞, 0}` (which is hopefully finite), you only have to compute the integrals over `{x, 0, 1 - ϵ/2}`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the reminder, I did not forget and checked that the same result comes out. With this simple simplification, I now manage to obtain one data point with `GlobalAdaptive` in about $14$ minutes with an accuracy of $1$% with the default `MaxErrorIncreases` setting.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher That makes sense, I will try that immediately and report. I have actually now put the $\epsilon$ on the $r$-coordinate (so integrating from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$) since it does not change my problem (I had two integrals before, one from $-\infty$ to $1-\epsilon/2$ and one from $1+\epsilon/2$ to $\infty$ which was highly inefficient). So the idea would be to integrate from $\epsilon$ to $1$ for example, and hope that this would be faster/more accurate. Then I just have to compute one time the integral from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: So the $\epsilon$ to $1$ integration is slightly longer than the one from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$. Still I think it is a good idea: I can do one time to $1$ to $\infty$ integration with great accuracy, and thus limit the error to the area $\epsilon$ to $1$ (which is there $\sim 0.7$% with `GlobalAdaptive` - much better than my starting values!).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This worked great, thanks a lot! Would you like to write your suggestions as an answer for the next users searching for similar solutions? Then I'd give you the bounty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can reduce the time by 3 times using the change of variables and method `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"`. In this case, the integral is calculated without messages and errors, we have code

```
\[Epsilon] = 10; y = r Cos[p] Sin[t]; z = r Sin[p] Sin[t]; \[Tau] = 
 r Cos[t];
d = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
I15 = 1/((1 - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \[Tau]^2) // FullSimplify;
R = (1 + \[Tau]4^2) I15;
S = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (\[Tau] - \[Tau]4)^2) I15 // FullSimplify;
a = 1/4 Sqrt[4*R*S - (1 - R - S)^2];
F = I Sqrt[-((1 - R - S - 4 I*a)/(1 - R - S + 4 I*a))];
Phi = 1/a Im[
    PolyLog[2, F Sqrt[R/S]] + Log[Sqrt[R/S]]*Log[1 - F Sqrt[R/S]]];
integrand = I15^3/d^(1/2) (4 \[Tau]^2 I15 - 1) Phi;
In[14]:= NIntegrate[
  integrand r^2 Sin[
    t], {\[Tau]4, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x, -\[Infinity], 
   1 - \[Epsilon]/2}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"] // Timing

(*Out[]= {217.781, -0.164111}*)
```

Update 1.
The second approach is mapping 4 coordinates onto a 4-sphere. The answer is slightly different from the 3-sphere, so we can evaluate the error of method `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"`:

```
\[Epsilon] = 10; y =

 r Cos[p3] Sin[p2] Sin[p1]; z = 
 r Sin[p3] Sin[p2] Sin[p1]; \[Tau] = r Cos[p2] Sin[p1]; \[Tau]4 = 
 r Cos[p1];
d = x^2 + y^2 + z^2;
I15 = 1/((1 - x)^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \[Tau]^2) // FullSimplify;
R = (1 + \[Tau]4^2) I15;
S = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + (\[Tau] - \[Tau]4)^2) I15 // FullSimplify;
a = 1/4 Sqrt[4*R*S - (1 - R - S)^2];
F = I Sqrt[-((1 - R - S - 4 I*a)/(1 - R - S + 4 I*a))];
Phi = 1/a Im[
    PolyLog[2, F Sqrt[R/S]] + Log[Sqrt[R/S]]*Log[1 - F Sqrt[R/S]]];
integrand = I15^3/d^(1/2) (4 \[Tau]^2 I15 - 1) Phi;

 NIntegrate[
  integrand r^3 Sin[p1]^2 Sin[p2], {x, -\[Infinity], 
   1 - \[Epsilon]/2}, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {p3, 0, 2 Pi}, {p2, 0, 
   Pi}, {p1, 0, Pi}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"] // Timing

(*Out[]= {239.531, -0.16635}*}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, spherical coordinates do indeed reduce the computational time even better than polar coordinates! That's an interesting thing for me to realize for future applications. But I kind of doubt the accuracy of the Monte Carlo method, especially when comparing your result to the one I had in the OP. I do need accurate results, so I might stick with `GlobalAdaptive` here.

Comment: @Jxx See Update 1 to my answer.